# MATLAB: Subindexing in cell array based on results of strfind

Tags: arrays, string, matlab, cell-array

I have a cell array, like so:

```
ID = {'g283', 'sah378', '2938349dgdgf', 'g283'};
```

I also have some data that corresponds to these IDs.

```
Data = {'data1', 'data2', 'data3', 'data4'};
```

Let's say my current ID is g283, and I want to extract Data that matches this ID.

I do `strfind(ID, 'g283')` and get a result like so:

```
result = {[1], [], [], [1]}
```

I now want to extract the data from data and get this:

new_data = ['data1', 'datat4'] or equivalent.

However, cell arrays cannot be subindexed into, so I am wondering if there is an easy method to do this without looping. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the input variables be defined as

```
ID = {'g283', 'sah378', '2938349dgdgf', 'g283'}; % ID
Data = {'data1', 'data2', 'data3', 'data4'}; % data
s = 'g283'; % current ID
```

You only need to apply [`isempty`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isempty.html) to test if each result of [`strfind`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strfind.html) contains a match or not. This can be done via [`cellfun`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html), for example as follows:

```
ind = cellfun(@(x) ~isempty(strfind(x, s)), ID);
new_data = Data(ind);
```

If you are looking for the whole string (as opposed to a partial match), a simpler alternative is to use [`ismember`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html):

```
ind = ismember(ID, s);
new_data = Data(ind);
```